# BigQuery Job Scheduler

Tags: google-bigquery

Someone leave from the company and leave me no clue about every job scheduler that he already made, some of the jobs that connected to datastudio stop working. is there a way I can find which job scheduler connect to the table?

Comment: What do you mean by "job scheduler"? [Scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)?

Comment: yap, scheduled queries @KyryloBulat

Answer (score 0):

You can find all Cloud Scheduler jobs here: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler/start?project=your-project-id

However, for BigQuery in particular, it's worth also checking the scheduled queries: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/scheduled-queries?project=your-project-id

Comment: what I want to say is, I have table let's say `company.table.customer` I need to find the schedule queries related to that table who run the update